# Sumar 2 simples variables usando el modelo MVC en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Muy buenas señores.... Estoy iniciando en esto, asi que requiero que me ayuden por favor, yo se que es algo simple, pero aun no entiendo porque estoy comenzando en este mundo.. lo que necesito es lo que dice el titulo, como hago para mostrar una simple suma de 2 variables, usando MVC de C#.
Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stack overflow, para ayudarte con tus dudas se necesita que muestres el codigo que llevas creado. Ademas, pasate en este link [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que formules mejor tus preguntas. Saludos.

Comment: Si sos principiante lo que primero tenes que hacer es investigar, luego comenzar con algo mas basico que mvc en web lo cual ya tiene mas conceptos que tenes que aprender. Para practicar y aprender, trabaja con Proyectos de consola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Documentación**

Asegurate de leer primero la documentación y de tener los requisitos previos para poder crear aplicaciones con MVC:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio-code

**Proyecto**

Es necesario crear un proyecto de MVC, para este ejemplo creamos la carpeta Demo y ahi generamos el template de MVC:

```
mkdir Demo
cd Demo
dotnet new mvc
```

**Modelo**

Creamos el modelo, que va a ser la clase que va a contener todas las propiedades con las que vamos a trabajar, creas el archivo `HomeViewModel` en la carpeta `Model`:

```
namespace Demo.Models
{
    public class HomeViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int Left { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Rigth { get; set; }
        [Editable(false)]
        public int Total { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Para este modelo agregue validaciones, la documentación esta [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

**Vista**

Modificamos la vista del Home para configurar nuestro modelo y agregar los campos de nuestra vista, para este caso usamos los [Tag Helpers](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-ES/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1) que nos van a ayudar a asociar los inputs con las propiedades, en este caso modificamos el archivo `Index.cshtml` dentro de la carpeta `Views/Home` para que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
@model Demo.Models.HomeViewModel

<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Left" required>
    <span>+</span>
    <input asp-for="Rigth" required>
    <span>=</span>
    <input asp-for="Total" readonly>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

**Controlador**

Por ultimo modificamos el controlador quien es quien va a realizar la lógica y recibir los parámetros de entrada de nuestra vista, en este caso modificaremos el archivo `HomeController` dentro de la carpeta `Controllers`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Demo.Models;

namespace Demo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index(HomeViewModel model)
        {
            model.Total = model.Left + model.Rigth;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

**Ejecutar**

Para poder ver todo funcionando debemos ejecutar la aplicacion, para esto solo basta con ejecutar el comando `dotnet run` dentro de la carpeta 'Demo' y posteriormente abrir en el navegador la pagina `https://localhost:5001/`

Comment: Gracias Daniel por tu gran apoyo. Esto es lo que necesitaba. Saludos